# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'?

Tags: python, string, user-interface, tkinter, integer

Hello I started python 3 days ago and here is my code

```
from tkinter import *



def my_name():
    score  = Entry_Test.get()
    if (score >= 80) :
            Label_Test.config(text="Grade A")
    elif (score >= 75):
            Label_Test.config(text="Grade B+")
    elif (score >= 70):
            Label_Test.config(text="Grade B")
    elif (score >= 65):
            Label_Test.config(text="Grade C+")
    elif (score >= 60):
            Label_Test.config(text="Grade C")
    elif (score >= 55):
            Label_Test.config(text="Grade D+")
    elif (score >= 50):
            Label_Test.config(text="Grade D")
    else:
            Label_Test.config(text="Grade F")

        


app = Tk() 
app.title('text gui')
app.geometry('600x400')
app.resizable(False,False)

Label_Test = Label(text='Put your grade')
Label_Test.pack()

text = ''
Entry_Test = Entry(textvariable=text)
Entry_Test.pack()

Button_Test = Button(text='Click me!',command=my_name)
Button_Test.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

idk if this code work or not becuase I am completely new to coding
but when I ran it **TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'** happend idk how to fix this can someone help me please.

Comment: `score = int(Entry_Test.get())`

Comment: Your entry test is a string (text) and you are comparing with an integer (number), which is not possible